# Type variable in Twirl page constructor

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl, type-variables

I want to do something like this:

```
 @import TypedCaseClass
 @(typedCaseClass: TypedCaseClass[T])(implicit request: RequestHeader, 
  messages: Messages){
   //...
 }
```

Not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a wildcard?

```
@import TypedCaseClass
@(typedCaseClass: TypedCaseClass[_])(implicit request: RequestHeader, 
  messages: Messages){
  //...
}
```

If you actually want to define a type parameter `T` for the template, then no, that's not possible. You could raise a feature request [here](https://github.com/playframework/twirl/issues).